# How do I insert special characters as text in XML editor for Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, math, symbols

So, I'm writing an app that involves using some mathematical symbols. I'm doing this in the visual XML editor. Is there any way I can get, say, an integral symbol, or a "less than or equal to" symbol? Things like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try put they as HTML.

```
String htmlStringWithMathSymbols = "&#8804;  &#8805;";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlStringWithMathSymbols));
```

Here you can display your math symbol in textView

Here the post http://www.hrupin.com/2011/12/how-to-put-some-special-math-symbols-in-textview-editview-or-other-android-ui-element

Hope, it help you!

Comment: I got it all figured out, and this is pretty much how I did it. I didn't create different strings like that, but instead just said "mInverse.setText (Html.fromHtml ("&alpha; ° &alpha; <sup>-1</sup> = &apsilon;"));"

Comment: The question asks for how to do it in the XML editor.

Answer (score 13):

```
Use &lt; for <, &gt; for > and &amp; for &.
```

or

```
<   less than   &lt;    
>   greater than    &gt;    
&   ampersand   &amp;   
¢   cent            &cent;  
£   pound           &pound; 
¥   yen         &yen;   
€   euro            &euro;  
§   section         &sect;  
©   copyright   &copy;  
®   registered trademark    &reg;   
™   trademark   &trade;
```

Comment: Cool, thank you :) is there a specific name for those that I can Google to find a list of them for mathematical symbols?

Comment: Actually, when I try adding this to the strings.xml file, it just comes out as literally that text. Is there a way around that?

Comment: These are HTML "character codes". Because `<` and `>`, for example, have a particular meaning in HTML, in order to write a literal `<`, `&lt;` is written instead. I am not familiar XML on Android, but perhaps if you place `<html>` tags around the related strings, then they will be replaced properly.
Note further, that there are not `greater-than-or-equal-to` or `less-than-or-equal-to` tags in HTML. There are, however, Greek symbols, such as capital Sigma (summation). Just do a search for <your character> "character code" html and it should be the first of the results, if it exists.

Comment: what we can use for = ?

Answer (score 2):

For inserting special unicode characters (including math symbols) in Android through XML, all you have to do is include the HTML code of the unicode character with the `&#<uni-code>;` in XML. For example, if you want to display the mathematical symbol 'Pi', in a button view of your XML file corresponding to your activity (main.xml for e.g.), you will have the following in main.xml:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:text="@string/button_pi"
    ...
</Button>
```

Then you will identify the string resource 'button_pi' included above, in the strings.xml file as detailed below

```
<string name="button_pi"> &#928;</string>
```

Now, when you build and run your code, you will see the symbol of pi displayed nicely in your view. 
The links below provide the complete table of HTML code for all uni-code character set (including all the special symbols)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 1):

I once had to do something similar to that, putting in foreign language characters in an XML file. The best, and as far as I know, and only way is to put the text you want to show in the strings.xml file and refer to them in the XML as `@string/your_text_declaration_here`. It's also generally good practice to put all text in the string.xml file regardless of special characters or not.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So, I found a list of unicode numbers for mathematical symbols (here: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf). Would I be able to use these somehow to get it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that all those symbols are supported in the Android font set but you can give them a try. Since the symbols in the PDF are not actually text characters, you're going to have to find the actual text character itself and then copy and paste that into your strings resources.

Comment: I tried adding things like &lt; into the strings.xml, but they just come out as the text "&lt;" haha. Is there a way around that? I've tried entering it in quotes, but don't think that helped.

Comment: Try using the literal characters rather than a code or alternative identifier; instead of "&lt" use "<". Hope that works!

Answer (score 1):

any of the following  `&int; &Integral;  &#x0222B;  &#8747;`  will produce an integral sign : ∫

∬ can be achieved with    `&Int;  &#x0222C;`
∭   can be achieved with     `&tint;` 
∮    can be achieved with      `&conint;`

Comment: Actually that gives 'Unresolved Entity Reference int' 'Unresolved Entity Reference Integral' in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial product for converting math / source code special symbols in XML text elements to valid XML with all the classes and starter source code to integrate into applications, allowing you to have special characters remain in your text elements (called XPL files rather than XML), and convert to valid XML during processing.

There is a free version that you can use from the command line that also ensures that your file types are as specified (for example ISO-8859-1 if you use characters like å,ä,ö, etc. s.c. latin-1 char set).

[Code from the High Level Logic Project](http://hll.nu)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="\u23F0"/>
```

will result in showing a clock

[image]

or in Kotlin:

```
myTextView.text = "\u23F0"
```