# How to display math symbols in textView Android

Tags: android-studio

I'm programming an android app in the form of math quiz game where the user chooses the correct answer and so I need to display the math equation symbols in TextViews , please how can i do that

Comment: It would be great if you can add what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML formatting.

These two posts can be very useful. I am not writing solution again because its not a new question and has been answered already.

**Check this links:**
[How do I insert special characters as text in XML editor for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613884/how-do-i-insert-special-characters-as-text-in-xml-editor-for-android/8613922)

https://www.hrupin.com/2011/12/how-to-put-some-special-math-symbols-in-textview-editview-or-other-android-ui-element